# Controlling Arduino-connected servos with the WiFly shield via an ad-hoc connection

Tags: client, arduino, telnet, adhoc

I'm trying to control some servos connected to an Arduino (breadboarded) over an ad-hoc connection. I've set up the network, can telnet into the [WiFly](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9954), and can even do some simple controls (for example, turning an LED on and off). However, when I try to start and stop a servo based on a character typed into the telnet session, the servo will run for half a second, then stop - after which the WiFly stops responding completely. My code for the LED works:

```cpp
void loop(){
    delay(100);
    index = 0;

    while(serialWiFly.available() > 0){
        if(index < 100){
            inputIn = serialWiFly.read();
            input[index] = inputIn;
            index++;
            input[index] = '\0';
        }
        if(inputIn == 'a')
            digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
        if(inputIn == 'z')
            digitalWrite(13, LOW);
    } //end while
    serialWiFly.flush();
    delay(10);
} //end loop
```

This lets me turn the LED on by pressing 'a', and off by pressing 'z'. Cool. But when I add a `moveForward()` function:

```cpp
void moveForward(){
    myservo.write(124);
}
```

And call it from my loop:

```cpp
if(inputIn == 'a') moveForward();
```

The servo will spin and then stop, as I've described. I'm at a loss here - how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone stumbles across this, I still don't know what caused it, but I fixed it by using an Arduino MiniPro instead of my standalone breadboarded unit. I believe it might have something to do with pulling the 'reset' pin HIGH or LOW (which I neglected to do in my breadboarded version.)